Can RNNs Learn Time-Bounded Distributions of Stochastic Processes and Time-Dependent Transition Densities?
I'm currently reading the book Applied Stochastic Differential Equations by Särkkä and Solin (link - page 234), where it is mentioned that one can calculate the maximum likelihood estimate (MLE) for a stochastic process if its transition densities are known.
I have a couple of questions, more out of curiosity than for a specific use case:

RNN Learning Distribution within Fixed Time Intervals: Suppose I simulate an SDE and generate multiple sample paths within a fixed time interval. If I use these sample paths as training data for a recurrent neural network (RNN), will the model be able to learn the distribution of the stochastic process? I understand that the model needs to be time-invariant to some extent, therefore, I only expect the RNN to learn the distribution of the process within the specific time interval I have generated the sample paths for. Is this expectation correct? Are there specific challenges or limitations to this approach, especially considering that the stochastic process can be non-stationary?

Neural Networks and Transition Density MLE: The transition densities of a stochastic process given by a SDE explicitly depends on time. If I were to provide time as an input feature to a RNN, could it learn to model the transition probabilities across all time points, effectively capturing the time-dependent nature of the process? What would be the potential pitfalls or challenges of using a neural network for this purpose compared to traditional MLE methods?


Any insights or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated.
